# Font-Size Responsive to DIV Size

Tags: html, css, responsive, font-size

I'm creating a page where I have some elements and they could be hidden or not. I'd like to know if it's possible to adjust my font-size according to my div?

For example, when I have 2 elements shown, I'd like my text to be bigger than when I have 5, so this way my text would fit better the space.

My JavaScript Code, which define if the element will be hidden or not.

```
var val_kpi = $("#t3_teste_B_kpi").text();
var val_kpi_clean = Number(val_kpi.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));

if (val_kpi_clean != null && val_kpi_clean != 0){
    $("#t3_teste_B").css("display", "");
}else{
    $("#t3_teste_B").css("display", "none");
}
```

```css
.tier3_test{
    width:50%;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 2.5px ;
    
    /*Configurações Visuais */
    background: #FFF;
    
    /*Configurações da Borda */
    border: 5px solid;
    border-image-slice: 1;
    /* border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px; */
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(to left, #2B6640, #66B512);
}
    
.flex-center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
    
.tier3_in{
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    width:100%;
}
    
    
.kpititle3{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    font-size: calc(8px + (12 - 8) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
}
    
    
.kpitext3 {
    font-size: calc(10px + (16 - 10) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
    font-weight: bold;
}
    
    
.no-wrap{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="tier3_test flex-center">
    <div class="tier3_in" id="t3_teste_A">
      <span class="kpititle3">A</span>
      <p><span class="kpitext3" id="t3_teste_A_kpi">VALOR 1</span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="tier3_in" id="t3_teste_B">
      <span class="kpititle3">B</span>
      <p><span class="kpitext3" id="t3_teste_B_kpi">VALOR 2</span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="tier3_in" id="t3_teste_C">
      <span class="kpititle3">C</span>
      <p><span class="kpitext3" id="t3_teste_C_kpi">VALOR 3</span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="tier3_in" id="t3_teste_D">
      <span class="kpititle3">D</span>
      <p><span class="kpitext3" id="t3_teste_D_kpi">VALOR 4</span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="tier3_in" id="t3_teste_E">
      <span class="kpititle3">E</span>
      <p><span class="kpitext3" id="t3_teste_E_kpi">VALOR 5</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Result I Have:
[image]

The Result I'd like to have:
[image]

Comment: Create a snippet reproducing your exact images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this using simple CSS.

Chris Coyier over at CSS-Tricks [explains the best solutions](https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/), and all use javascript. However, there is no point figuring it out yourself - Coyier discusses a few already-written libraries that do the job for you.

Below is an example using your code and the first such library: Dave Rupert’s [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/) library. Click the button to see what happens when three divs are removed.

[<kbd>jsFiddle Demo (StackSnippets not working at the moment)</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/9g3hkocz/)

```js
var grow_factor = $('.tier3_in').length / 2;
$('.tier3_test').fitText( grow_factor );

/* Below is just to remove divs for demo... */
$('button').click(function(){
   $('#t3_teste_C, #t3_teste_D, #t3_teste_E').remove();
   var grow_factor = $('.tier3_in').length / 2;
   $('.tier3_test').fitText( grow_factor );
});
```

```css
.tier3_test{
    width:50%;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 2.5px ;
    
    /*Configurações Visuais */
    background: #FFF;
    
    /*Configurações da Borda */
    border: 5px solid;
    border-image-slice: 1;
    /* border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px; */
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(to left, #2B6640, #66B512);
}
    
.flex-center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
    
.tier3_in{
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    width:100%;
}
    
    
.kpititle3{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
}
    
.no-wrap{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.fittext.js"></script>

<div class="tier3_test flex-center">
    <div class="tier3_in" id="t3_teste_A">
      <span class="kpititle3">A</span>
      <p><span class="kpitext3" id="t3_teste_A_kpi">VALOR 1</span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="tier3_in" id="t3_teste_B">
      <span class="kpititle3">B</span>
      <p><span class="kpitext3" id="t3_teste_B_kpi">VALOR 2</span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="tier3_in" id="t3_teste_C">
      <span class="kpititle3">C</span>
      <p><span class="kpitext3" id="t3_teste_C_kpi">VALOR 3</span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="tier3_in" id="t3_teste_D">
      <span class="kpititle3">D</span>
      <p><span class="kpitext3" id="t3_teste_D_kpi">VALOR 4</span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="tier3_in" id="t3_teste_E">
      <span class="kpititle3">E</span>
      <p><span class="kpitext3" id="t3_teste_E_kpi">VALOR 5</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
<button>Remove 3 Divs</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript, simply add / remove one of two extra-classes (`.big-font` and `.small-font`)to your wrapper div (`.tier-3-test`) in function of if its elements are removed or not. In your css, you then define a font-size for extra class 1 which is added if the wrapper div contains all 5, and another font-size for extra class 2 which is added if the wrapper div contains less divs, more or less like so:

```
.big-font {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.small-font {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```